# testing for operator. error converting to double? (calculator app)

Tags: vb.net

So I'm just doing this basic calculator thing trying to learn more VB. I've got this app the has 3 textboxes, a user enters in 2 values (1 in each box) and then an operator in the 3rd box (+, -, *, /)

I have a method here that checks if the user entered in an operator:

```
Private Function isOperator(ByVal textBox As TextBox, ByVal name As String)
    Dim strOperatorList As String() = {"+", "-", "/", "*"}
    If Not strOperatorList.Contains(textBox.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show(name & " does not contain a valid operator.", "Entry Error")
        textBox.SelectAll()
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

And I'm pretty sure that's working. I'm getting an error here in my button click:

```
Try
        If IsValidData() Then
            Dim operand1 As Decimal = CDec(txtOperand1.Text)
            Dim operand2 As Decimal = CDec(txtOperand2.Text)
            Dim strOperator As Double = CDbl(txtOperator.Text)
            Dim result As Decimal = operand1 + strOperator + operand2

            txtResult.Text = result
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &
                        ex.GetType.ToString & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &
                        ex.StackTrace, "Exception")
    End Try
```

Error is in line:

```
Dim strOperator As string = txtOperator.Text
```

The error says:

```
Conversion from string "+" to type Double is not valid.
```

I tried changing the string to double and casting the textbox to a double but I still get the same error. Am I just declaring it wrong?

Comment: the "+" character is a character not a double: `Dim strOperator As Double = CDbl(txtOperator.Text)` which is different than the text you posted.  This is wrong too: `Dim result As Decimal = operand1 + strOperator + operand2` you cant get a math result my gluing a string together with 2 doubles; your code will have to do the math.  It might LOOK like the same error, but you could get it once for '+' to double, then later when gluing the math together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert your operator to a number, use a string:

```
Dim operator As String = txtOperator.Text
```

Then, you can't use a string as an operator, as the string is data, and an operator is part of the code. Determine from the operator what to do with the values:

```
Dim result As Decimal
If operator = "+" Then
  result = operand1 + operand2
ElseIf operstor = "-" Then
  result = operand1 - operand2
ElseIf operator = "/" Then
  result = operand1 / operand2
ElseIf operator = "*" Then
  result = operand1 * operand2
Else
  ' Oops, unknown opreator
End If
```

Comment: yeah that worked! I can't believe I didn't know that.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try
    If IsValidData() Then
        Dim operand1 As Decimal = CDec(txtOperand1.Text)
        Dim operand2 As Decimal = CDec(txtOperand2.Text)
        Dim strOperator As String = txtOperator.Text
        Dim result as Decimal
        Select Case strOperator
           Case "+"
              result = operand1 + operand2                  
           Case "-"
              result = operand1 - operand2                 
           Case "*"
              result = operand1 * operand2                  
           Case "/"
              result = operand1 / operand2
           Case Else
              'error
        end Select                 

        txtResult.Text = result
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &
                    ex.GetType.ToString & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &
                    ex.StackTrace, "Exception")
End Try
```